# How can I set split string in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have structure as below

```html
<input type="text" class="search-hotels" placeholder="" data-other-placeholder="Test 1|Test 2|Test3"/>
```

and as you see I have `data-other-placeholder` attribute and I split my string with (`|`) bracket

```js
var placeTarget = $(".search-hotels"),
    getPlaceholder = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder"),
    splitData     = getPlaceholder.split("|");
```

and I want to assign this string in a array list and print result how can I do that ?

Comment: console.log(splitData) ? This seems correct, what's the issue?

Comment: The split function returns by default an array, what else do you need more?

Comment: I want to result like this `var placeholderText = [
    "Where would you like to go?",
    "Amsterdam?", 
    "Paris?", 
    "Berlin?", 
    "London?", 
    "New York?", 
    "San Francisco?"
  ];`

Comment: The splitData variable is an array because you use the split function

Comment: I didn't know split returns array..so I want to print them one by one in html with comma

Comment: So you want to format the resulting array as a string for display ? You can do it with a simple "for" command, with adding some ' [ ', ' ] ' and ' " ' characters. For the quote character, beware to escape it if you use it in a literal declared with quotes too : "Bryan says \"I am in the kitchen\"" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery each, for each array item you run a function.
Use `.append` to output your HTML to target element like here I'm target the `id="output"` element to output my result.

```
$.each(splitData, function( index, value ) {
  $('#output').append('<div>'+value+'</div>');
});
```

```js
var placeTarget = $(".search-hotels"),
  getPlaceholder = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder"),
  splitData = getPlaceholder.split("|");

//$('#output').text('"' + splitData.join('","') + '"');

$('#output').append(document.createTextNode('"' + splitData.join('","') + '"'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search-hotels" placeholder="" data-other-placeholder="Test 1|Test 2|Test3" />
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: so can we print it like this ``"Test1","Test 2"`

Comment: @canon thanks for the tip, you mean I should create the whole element block then append at the end of each loop? like the callback?

Comment: @canon how about this one: `$('#output').append('"' + splitData.join('","') + '"');`

Comment: @canon I just did some research, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.prototype.split()` already returns an array-- iterate over it and use `Array.prototype.push()` to [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control) new values to your array.

So in your example...

```js
var testString = 'test|test1|test2';

var arrayToPush = ['Where would you like to go?'];

var testStringParsed = testString.split('|');

for(var i = 0; i < testStringParsed.length; i++){
  var string = testStringParsed[i];
  arrayToPush.push(string + '?');
}

console.log(arrayToPush);
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"assign this string in a array list"*

You're doing this on your last line:

```
 splitData = getPlaceholder.split("|");
```

> *"and print result"*

You can do that with:

```
console.log(splitData);
```

But you can also interate over the array and print results one by one, with a simple *for* or with something like this:

```
splitData.forEach(function(element, index){
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted so much, I thought you did a good job at answering the question.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet maybe cause he change the subject on comments without change the question...